# Ignore ERR_SSL_FALLBACK_BEYOND_MINIMUM_VERSION

Tags: ssl, chromium

I upgraded Chromium. When I access the `webadmin` in my printer using `https` I now get:

> ```
> ERR_SSL_FALLBACK_BEYOND_MINIMUM_VERSION
> ```

This is probably due to the removal of `SSL < 3.0 in Chromium`.

Since there is no new firmware for the printer it will never run `SSL 3.0`, and I am not going to destroy a perfectly good printer just because of my browser. So is there a way I can ask Chromium to allow for `SSL < 3.0` for this particular website?

Comment: When you say SSL < 3, you mean SSLv2 ? Did you try with another browser (Firefox, Opera, IE...), even an outdated one (not Mosaic) ?
Is there an HTTP interface ?

Answer (score 0):

From Chrome 50, TLS version fallback has been removed.

launch Chrome with --ssl-version-fallback-min=tls1.1

It can set the default minimum fallback version

but SSL < 3.0, I don't know if it works

Reference

- [Remove insecure TLS version fallback](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5685183936200704)
- [Issue 583787](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=583787)